# A aroma/flavor hops taxonomy

Tags: hops

I would like to gain some knowledge about hops and have an idea in what all those varieties differ. Is it possible to define a few categories for hops (for example based on region of origin), so to choose one variety from each group and start knowing the differences between different categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a rudimentary takeoff on the flavor wheels you can find.

this one is for hop aromas/flavors:

[image]
(source: http://cdn.homebrewtalk.com/attachments/f12/102717d1361410242-hops-aroma-flavor-wheel-hops-flavors-reference-wheel.jpg)

Comment: I've fixed the image link you posted To insert an image, click the icon that looks like a picture, and select "insert an image from the web" - you can then enter the image url there.

Answer (score 0):

Now that this question is "reopened" I have found a couple of very good resources for this:

Hop Union has an aroma finder: http://www.hopunion.com/aroma-wheel/
The way this is set up is that each aroma is split into 3 groups and each group is alphabetical (so where the alpha order "resets" is the start of the next group) and each hop has up to 3 aromas and the higher the group the more dominant the aroma is for that hop. Ex. Citra is in group 2 for Fruity and group 1 for Citrus so Citrus is a more dominant trait.

Another good resource is the Barth Haas Flavor Wheel: http://www.barthhaasgroup.com/wheel/
They also have this in a variety portfolio PDF version: http://www.barthhaasgroup.com/images/pdfs/hop-varieties/13-10899_uebersicht_Rohhopfen-EN_FH.pdf

(I know links are generally frowned upon since they could go away but I'm not sure how to embed this data since its a bit more complicated).

Answer (score -2):

I'm late to the game here, but for anyone else who lands here, try this: http://www.bertusbrewery.com/2013/03/dry-hopped-bud-light.html

Comment: What does that have to do with the question?